# htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities() not working

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
$currentPage = SITE_URL.'/'.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."?".substr($tail,1);
//For example a URL 'http://php.net/docs.php
'
$currentPage = htmlspecialchars($currentPage);
//$currentPage = htmlentities($currentPage);

//I was hoping for a output like this 'http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fdocs.php  '
echo $currentPage;  //but I get http://php.net/docs.php again
```

I get exactly the same output as the input

Comment: Use $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] instead of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] can be tricked by going to /index.php/someotherpage.php. Apart from that, what the others said.

Comment: @igorw he's already sanitizing that

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel he is preventing XSS, but basename will still give him the wrong result (eg. 'someotherpage.php').

Comment: @igorw WHOM? an attacker? Fair user will never face wrong url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). It will encode `http://php.net/docs.php` to `http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fdocs.php` like you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual:

> This function is identical to
>   htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except
>   with htmlentities(), all characters
>   which have HTML character entity
>   equivalents are translated into these
>   entities.

So without seeing the original input, I can only assume that the original input does not contain any characters that can be translated.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the same output, there was nothing to escape.

`htmlentities()` is supposed to transform `<` and `>` or `&` into entity equivalents. It leaves other ASCII characters like `/` or `:` alone. So your URL probably only contained those, but no `&` for example.